# Is a network connection always a single network address?

Tags: authentication

With a figure showing a communication between a network and a server, does that indicate a single network address or can it include multiple network addresses?  Is a single network address the same as an IP address ?  Does a patent figure showing a communication between a network and a server indicated an IP address or can it accommodate multiple IP addresses?

Comment: ...can we see the figure you're discussing?

Comment: It really depends on the figure/diagram/drawing and what is was created to communicate.  It could really be a number of things in either a logical or a physical sense such as: a single physical connection, multiple connections with some sort of link aggregation, a single IP, multiple IPs, a single service on the server, a trunk providing access to multiple VLANs, a very high level indication that it is connected to the network and nothing more specific than that, or something else entirely..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that unless you have multiple NICs sending data to the server there would only be 1 network address. If you were to unplug from the network there is a possibility that when you plug back up that you would obtain a different IP address.

If only one device is connected to the server then I would think that there would only be 1 IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if we are talking about a continuous stream of information, then it has to be a single IP address.  The packet has to use the IP address for translation purposes.

In general, even with a single port NIC or a single port on a switch, you can configure multiple IP addresses for it, but any single stream for a specific application or use will translate to only one IP address.  Of course, there is NIC teaming, but that isn't really what you are asking about.

When it comes to diagrams, they usually define the network at an instant or for a specific event.  For instance, a DHCP request or a single IP packet.  In those cases, yes, the single connection translates to a single IP address as they only ever have a single destination (even broadcast is a single destination, just switches then flood the broadcast packet).  Basically, the fact that your server, workstation or other has multiple IP addresses has very little effect on the transmission of single things.